# Materialize CSS - multiple select with disabled selected issue

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Even on official [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/select.html) page for Select when you select a value for multiple select you see the `disabled selected` "Choose your Option" and then the selected option(s).

[image]

It seems to me more user friendly to shoe only `Option 1` as "Choose your option" is not a valid option.

I use the

```
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
```

so once page is rendered the user got a hint what is required of them.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/eL7uvz6s/3/).

It seems to me that using jQuery solves this issue (see an [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/materialize/materialize_selects.htm)) but I am using pure javascript only.

So the question is `How to not display disabled, selected` text for multiple MaterializeCSS select.

Comment: Not sure about MaterialCss stuff but you can just give an inline style to option `<option vlaue="" disabled selected style="display:none">Choose your option</option>` and the option will be hidden.

Comment: @stillKonfuzed it did not help https://jsfiddle.net/radek/eL7uvz6s/11/

Comment: So you just want to hide the first option that says choose but keep its value and must be selected on load and disabled? How about just removing the Option text?

Comment: removing text? I am try to deselect the very fist option on "onchange". look bit complicated to me

Comment: Got it! Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from your js fiddle , this will fix your unselect issue.

```
function  onSelectChange(s){
  const elOptions = s.querySelectorAll('option')
  elOptions[0].removeAttribute('selected') // this won't work
  elOptions[0].selected  = false; ///this will - tested //first option will be unselected
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the code and comments. `this wont work` doesnt seem too promissing. My working jsFiddle is here. Dont forget to add select in case no option is selected https://jsfiddle.net/radek/eL7uvz6s/19/

Comment: I am sorry, use `elOptions[0].selected  = false;` instead of `elOptions[0].removeAttribute('selected')` for unselecting, thats all I wanted to say. like this https://jsfiddle.net/en93t0kh/

Comment: I cannot accept is as an answer. It does not cover all possibilities.

Comment: Sure sure! I just wanted to help, I am new to code formatting in stackoverflow, so code in comments is not well formatted so had to post as answer.